# Is it possible to speedup Get-Mailboxstatistics for exchange online?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I need to run `Get-MailboxStatistics` for 4000 users, I'm thinking there is a way to speedup `Get-MailboxStatistics`.

I have read in a forum how to use `Get-MailboxStatistics -Server`, but I think it cannot be used for Exchange Online. As we don't know the servers where the mailboxes are.

Can I use the below cmdlet:

```
$MailboxStat = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Get-MailboxStatistics $mailbox.UserPrincipalName |
        Select-Object TotalItemSize,DisplayName 
 }
```

I just need `TotalItemSize` and `DisplayName` for each mailbox user. I don't know whether this will really speedup.

Comment: Putting your command inside `Invoke-Command` will not speed it up. `Invoke-Command` can be used to run script blocks in parallel on remote computers, but that is not what you are trying to accomplish here. You could use the [Job cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs/) or [Runspaces](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/28/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-3/) to run tasks in parallel on your system.

Comment: Can you further clarify what you mean by "Speed up"?  Are you already looping through each of the 4000 users and running the Get-MailboxStatistics command and it's not getting the results fast enough?  Are you running the above code against each mailbox individually?

Comment: Yes i am running in loop for 4000 user , Get-MailboxStatistics is taking one second to retrieve the details.  i m  running against each mailbox individually

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can Export directly from portal https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/reportsUsage/MailboxUsage

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but you can use the updated cmdlets: Get-EXOMailboxStatistics -PropertySets to specify which properties you want to return, slightly faster but still slow.